# Group time stamps by shift

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

In our factory, we have following shifts:

- 1: Mo - Fri: 5am - 1pm
- 2: Mo - Fri: 1pm - 9pm
- 3: Mo - Fri: 9pm - 5am
- 4a: Sat: 5am - 5pm
- 4b: Sun: 5pm - Mon 5am

In a certain table we have several date time entries which I'd like to group using a query. For shift 1, 2 and 3, this query works fine::

```
  CASE
WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.date_time_stamp) >= 5 AND DATEPART(hh, c.date_time_stamp) < 13 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.date_time_stamp, 103) + ' shift 1'
WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.date_time_stamp) >= 13 AND DATEPART(hh, c.date_time_stamp) < 21 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.date_time_stamp, 103) + ' shift 2'
WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.date_time_stamp) >= 21 AND DATEPART(hh, c.date_time_stamp) < 24 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.date_time_stamp, 103) + ' shift 3'
WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.date_time_stamp) >= 00 AND DATEPART(hh, c.date_time_stamp) < 5 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -1, c.date_time_stamp), 103)  + ' shift 3'  END AS shift,
```

This gives me some kind of shift_id. To identify shift 4a and 4b I could extend the case statement but I'm a bit worried about the performance of the query.

Can anyone give me a tip how to create a function that returns a shift_id in an efficient way? Thank you!

EDIT: Some example data:

```
inventory_trans_number creation_dt             shift_id             shift_type container_code
---------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- ---------- ------------------
140952                 2013-02-04 01:03:19.043 20130203 03          3          154143591115247892
140956                 2013-02-04 01:07:20.343 20130203 03          3          154143591115247939
140962                 2013-02-04 01:10:56.417 20130203 03          3          154143591115247991
140968                 2013-02-04 01:14:55.250 20130203 03          3          154143591115248134
140970                 2013-02-04 01:17:18.883 20130203 03          3          154143591115248196
141070                 2013-02-04 02:12:59.327 20130203 03          3          154143591115248240
141076                 2013-02-04 02:16:27.480 20130203 03          3          154143591115248356
141092                 2013-02-04 02:22:44.067 20130203 03          3          154143591115248530
141096                 2013-02-04 02:25:02.157 20130203 03          3          154143591115248585
141102                 2013-02-04 02:33:51.253 20130203 03          3          154143591115248615
```

Comment: If you're worried about the performance, add an extra column for the shift ID. Either as a computed column with a persisted value or using a trigger that calculates the shift ID on insert/update. Put an index on that, done.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I've thought about that earlier but it's a table of an external database (it's not ours, it's the database of the WMS system)...

Comment: @KoenVC given the above sample data, what is your expected results if you run the assumed-function?

Comment: Then you should at least work with `BETWEEN ... AND` to allow use of an index, if one exists. Using `DATEPART` results in a table scan, which is slow. However if no index exists on `date_time_stamp` then it won't matter as there will be a table scan anyway.

Comment: @KoenVC can you provide us with sample data for `In a certain table`?

Comment: Does the `4a` shift actually end on **Sun** 5pm?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the shifts. It works by realising that this is a mathematical problem, not a database one.

There are 21 shifts per week and we create a table variable to hold the shift names - you may want to create a permenant table for this with an index on the Number column.

By getting a `DATEDIFF` by hours between the time and datetime that is set to 5:00 on a monday *before* any of the dates we are interested in and taking the modulo of this with 24*7 (the number of hours in a week) we get a number indicating what hour it is past 5:00 on Monday (i.e. shift 0). Divide this by 8 and you get the shift number.

```
DECLARE @FirstEverShift datetime = CONVERT(datetime, '2011-12-26 05:00')

DECLARE @ShiftTypes TABLE
(Number int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Shift  nvarchar(2) NOT NULL)

INSERT @ShiftTypes
VALUES
(0, '1'),
(1, '2'),
(2, '3'),
(3, '1'),
(4, '2'),
(5, '3'),
(6, '1'),
(7, '2'),
(8, '3'),
(9, '1'),
(10, '2'),
(11, '3'),
(12, '1'),
(13, '2'),
(14, '3'),
(15, '4a'),
(16, 'NA'),
(17, 'NA'),
(18, '4b'),
(19, 'NA'),
(20, 'NA')

SELECT  s.date_time_stamp
        ,st.Shift
FROM    shifts s
        INNER JOIN
        @ShiftTypes st ON st.Number=DATEDIFF(HOUR, @FirstEverShift, s.date_time_stamp) % (24*7) / 8
```

**Edit**

I realised that the weekend shifts are 12 hours not 8. This approach works but will need modification which I'm not going to do because I'm on a tablet!

Instead of dividing by 8, divide by 4, this means the table variable has to go from 0 to 40 and each 8 hour shift takes 2 numbers and each 12 hour takes 3.

Comment: Hi Dale, I'll give this a try!